# XIAOMI DnsProxyBlocker bug

Tags: android

I've found a strange problem on my XIAOMI (Android 6.0.1, MIU 8.2.1.0). I'm using the Firebase auth service and everything is working ok but not in my XIAOMI where I  can make requests to Google services only time to time. I don't know why smartphone is locking some dns requests.

See below:

```
I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, method: 1 ]
07-24 19:33:55.936 6263-7413/? I/Email: onHandleIntent accountNUmber = 1
07-24 19:33:55.979 286-2130/? D/DnsProxyBlocker: hasUid: restrict uid(10008)
07-24 19:33:55.979 286-2130/? E/DnsProxyListener: block dns query from uid = 10008
07-24 19:33:55.979 286-2130/? W/FrameworkListener: Handler 'getaddrinfo' error (Success)
07-24 19:33:55.981 5208-6955/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
07-24 19:33:55.983 5208-6911/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onFailure
07-24 19:33:55.991 6263-6373/? I/Exchange: Ping task starting for 1
07-24 19:33:56.008 6505-6505/.... E/--------->: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., null
```

Anybody know what to do? Thanks

P.S.

Cheap smartphone with Android 5.1 work Ok, but not XIAOMI MI4 , may be it's not a phone problem. But as I understood DnsProxyBlocker is their feature.